# Match 2 arrays keys and show value of second array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays that I need to match and post the result.

```
$arr1 = 1,3,4;

$arr2 = 1 => 'Title1'
        2 => 'Title2'
        3 => 'Title3'
        4 => 'Title4'
```

I want to get the result to show the matched keys (number matches) to then show the value of `$arr2`

The above should result in Title1, Title3, title4

I have tried `array_key_exists` but i think im getting myself confused over something simple.

```
       foreach($arr1 as $a)
        {
            if(array_key_exists($a, $arr2))
            {
                $new[$a] = $arr2[$a];
                    }
        }   
$l=1;
foreach($new as $n => $ob){

    echo '<p>'.$new[$l][0].'">'.$new[$l][0].'</p>';
    ++$l;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, where does $d come from ? It should be $a.
And $n sould be used instead of $l (which is useless) and thus, not incremented.

To simplify your code, you could have written :

```
<?php
foreach($arr1 as $k){
    if(array_key_exists($k, $arr2)){
    // or : if(isset($arr2[$k])){
        echo $arr2[$k] . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I preferred your answer in the end. Merci.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you can use like this

```
  $arr1 = [1,3,4];
  $arr2 = [1 => 'Title1', 2 => 'Title2', 3 => 'Title3', 4 => 'Title4'];
   foreach($arr1 as $key){
      echo "\n". $arr2[$key];
   }
```

You can also check existence by `isset` first

Live demo : https://eval.in/720926